# How can I paginate the data of a relationship LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I would like to know how I can paginate the called data of a relationship in Laravel, I do not want to load all the information in the same route, couse it would make the load heavier

I have categories and products, in the resource categories, I am calling the products through a relationship, but what I need to do is paginate those products

I need that in the route api/category/1, it returns the name of the category and the products on that specific category, (witch is working) but need those products paginated.

In my category controller:

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $category = Category::findOrFail($id);
    return new CategoryResource($category);
}
```

In my category model I have:

```
 public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

In my category resource I have:

```
 return [

        'name' => $this->name,
       //staff
        'products' => $this->products,
    ];
```

What I need to do is paginate that `'products' => $this->products,` I already try `'products' => $this->products->paginate(5),` but of course dont works, also try `return $this->hasMany('App\Product'->paginate(5));` in my model but it also doesn't work.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If you did `$this->products()->paginate(5);`, you should get a paginated result. Alternatively, you could query `Product` directly, like `Product::where("category_id", "=", $categoryId)->paginate(5);`, etc etc.

Comment: AHAAHAHAHAHA I miss the () in $this->products()->paginate(5); :blush thank you!!!!

Comment: No worries, it happens! A lot of methods of `Collection` (`$this->products`) overlap with the `Builder` (`$this->products()`), but unfortunately, `->paginate()` is not one of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntax error, only one parenthesis was missing in: `'products' => $this->products()->paginate(5)`